# .py не запускается из командной строки

Tags: python, cmd

я запускаю программу которую сам написял консоль ошибок не выдает и перекидывает в мой код [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Неправильно запускаешь. Минус за огромный скриншот.

Comment: Спс я понял ты лудший

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Бро зачем такие сложности, в конце кода любой программы пишем input() далее делаешь по умолчанию что бы любой файл с расширением .py открывался командной строкой pyton та что устанавливается с питоном, и вуаля любой такой файл открываем 2 мя кликами левой кнопкой мыши, как обычную программу, input() нужен для того что бы после выполнения всего когда интерпретатор не закрывался автоматически ибо ты не успеешь прочесть результат...

Через смд когда запускаешь нужно перед названием файла ставить pyton далее название файла, это нужно для того что бы смд понял что ты собираешься выполнять его в среде питона, или по русски говоря он не понимает как его открыть, смд использует sheell, а тот в свою очередь не соображает, если ты будешь открывать файл к примеру штатной командной строкой windows, то всё получиться как написанно у тебя на скрине, ибо она понимает что нужно открывать файл в среде Пайтона.

И ещё один ньюанс если ты что то не правильно написал в коде, и открываешь файл ЛКМ как я описал, то командная строка просто быстро откроется и закроется, ошибки как в интерактивном режиме она не покажет..

Comment: Пожалуйста, обратите внимание: у нас не форум, один ответ нужно постить в одном сообщении, а не в трёх.

Answer (score 2):

Вы не запускаете код, а отдаёте системе команду открыть файл редактором по умолчанию.

***Пример запуска:***

```
python t.py
```

```
py t.py
```

Answer (score 0):

```
chmod +x t.py
```

Чтобы добавить возможность запускать файл как исполняемый.

```
./t.py
```

Чтобы запустить исполняемый файл в текущем директории.

Comment: Нужно уточнить, что это будет работать под Linux и другими unix-подобными системами (у автора вопроса Windows, что понятно по скриншоту). Также стоит упомянуть про shbang - без него файл не запустится.